# WPF Binding Question - Change Label Text based on Modifier Key Control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a context menu, that I'd like to change the Header based on whether the Control Key is pressed or not.

Right now I have,

```
<MenuItem Header="Send To">
  <MenuItem ... />
  <MenuItem ... />
</MenuItem>
```

I'd like based on the Control Key being down to be,

```
<MenuItem Header="Move To">
  <MenuItem ... />
  <MenuItem ... />
</MenuItem>
```

All I really need to do is change the Header text, because inside the code I know how to check for the Modifier key being Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `Header` to some property in your view model, and have it change (with notification) when the modifier key is pressed.

Comment: I've tried this Aviad, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I can update the title of the application, and it switches back and forth with control being down/up.  But the header in the context menu doesn't change, in fact it is blank.  Here is what I have.

<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding ElementName=winMain, Path=myContextMenu}" KeyDown="KeyDown_Handler" KeyUp="KeyUp_Handler">
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=SendTo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
...
myContextMenu is a class that echo's property change events for the SendTo property

Do I have the binding coded correctly?

Comment: Nop, the binding is not correct, it's a XAML namespace issue. The object referenced to by the `ContextMenu` property of whatever element it's applied to, does not belong to the namespace of the window. Therefore you can't use `ElementName` binding on it and have it refer to the window.

Comment: Some more clarifications: The `ContextMenu` cannot paricipate in any logical or visual hierarchy, therefore it does not inherit any `DataContext` nor is it part of the namespace of its so-called 'container' since it's not really its container after all, at least not until the user invokes it. When that happens, its `DataContext` is set to its container's `DataContext` but only if it doesn't have a local value assigned to its own `DataContext` property, which in your case it does. What you'd expect is for WPF to assign the `DataContext` first, and then evaluate the binding, but thatsnotthecase

Comment: A year later - thanks for your answer Aviad, I may try it out sometime.  I ended up with watching KeyDown and KeyUp on the ContextMenu.  It was a tough nut to crack, WPF isn't my forte.